# Mongoimport of json file works but db.foo.find() doesn't display

Tags: json, mongodb, find

What am I missing here?  300 objects imported, but I can't see them with a find()

Import JSON file:

```
mongoimport --host localhost -db foo -collection bar --file onebigline.json
connected to: localhost
Tue Sep 11 10:36:58 imported 300 objects
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
```

Start Mongo

```
connecting to: test
> show dbs
foo 0.203125GB
local   (empty)
> use foo
switched to db foo
```

show imported JSON data from db foo

```
> db.foo.find()
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your collection name from the `mongoimport` command is `bar`, not `foo`, so try:

```
> db.bar.find()
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried db.foo.bar.find() but no db.bar.find().  That worked!  Thank you.